# Button to transfer me to next page and start a game

Tags: android, button

It's hard to explain in the title. Basically as far as I can tell the submit button is taking the name and placing it in the array like I want. What I need now is for the Play(done) Button to transfer the user and the data to the next class (which I believe is coded correctly) and I need it to start a game. The game which you will see in the second class (get the data from the previous) I need it to display the names from the names array 1 at a time and randomly assign them a task to do from the tasks array.

Currently the app is force closing after I click the play button. I'm linking both classes cause I'm pretty sure the problem is in the second class. Thanks for your help ahead of time.

Class1

```
public class Class1 extends Activity
{
    int players=0;
    String names[];

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.class1);

    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameinput);

    final ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();



    Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View submit1)
        {
            players++;
            for(int i=0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                names.add(input.getText().toString());

                input.setText("");
            }
        }
    });

    Button doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done_btn);
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View done1)
        {
            Intent done = new Intent(Class1.this, Game.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putStringArrayList("arrayKey", names);

            done.putExtra("players", players);
            //done.putExtra("names", names[players]);
            startActivity(done);
        }
    });
}
```

Game Class

```
public class Game extends Activity
{
    int players, counter=0, score, ptasks,rindex;
    String[] names, tasks;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);

    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    String[] names = bundle.getStringArray("arrayKey");

    Intent game = getIntent();
    players = game.getIntExtra("players", 1);
    //names = game.getStringArrayExtra("names");

    Random generator = new Random();

    tasks[0]= "";
    tasks[1]= "";
    tasks[2]= "";
    tasks[3]= "";
    tasks[4]= "";
    tasks[5]= "";
    tasks[6]= "";
    tasks[7]= "";
    tasks[8]= "";
    tasks[9]= "";



    while (counter <5)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < players; i++)
        {
            TextView name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pname);
            name1.setText( names[i]+":");

            ptasks = 10;
            rindex = generator.nextInt(ptasks);

            TextView task = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.task);
            task.setText( tasks[rindex]);


        }
        Button failButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fail_btn);
        failButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View failed)
            {

            }
        });

        Button notButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notbad_btn);
        notButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View notbad)
            {

            }
        });

        Button champButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.champ_btn);
        champButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View champp)
            {

            }
        });


        counter++;
    }


}
```

Thought I should also mention that these buttons on the 2nd page I would like to assign a score to whichever name array person is up and keep track until the final round where it will display the winner. If anyone has any idea how to make that work.

Comment: Every Force Close should print a StackTrace into the DDMS console. Could you share it with us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made sure to include the Game activity as an Application Node in your AndroidManifest?

If not, open your manifest to the application tab, on the bottom hit Add, and add an Activity of the name .Game

Without this, that intent never gets received by the other class.

Comment: Yes, its there. And I'm not seeing any problems with the code that I can tell that's why its confusing me.

Comment: Well i'm not sure how else ot help unless you can show us your LogCat or a stacktrace to find the root behind your force close issue.  Run it under debug, and copypasta the bad stuff to us.

Answer (score 0):

You've already been told that you use non-initialized arrays here: [EditText and using buttons to submit them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5771703/170842). But also you're trying to get array extra, however you don't put it inside intent. And you're using uninitialized `tasks` array in `Game` class.

Comment: Ya you're right. I blocked certain pieces out and and it sent me to the next page fine it wasnt until I unblocked the tasks that it went wrong. The getarrayextra i commented out because I was keeping it their unless previous help didn't work out I could bring it back to try someone elses. What would you say is the best way to initialize that tasks array?

Comment: So i initialized the tasks and names and it now opens the screen without force closing and is randomly selecting a task like i want. The problem now is 1. the names aren't transferring over correctly and 2. still not sure how to set a score to a name?

Comment: 0. `String[] tasks = new String[MAX_TASK_COUNT]`, for example. 1. Names aren't transferring because you don't transfer them. Call `done.putExtra("names", names)` to transfer names. 3. Use `Map`.